# Jquery - find DOM element with most characters inside

Tags: jquery, find, element

I have few paragraphs and I need to find the one which has the most characters inside. I am fairly new to Javascript and I can't figure out how to select that one. I can find number of characters by using .each() and .length() but I how do I addClass to the one with most?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sort them by number of characters, and the last one in the collection will be the one with the most characters :

```
var longest = $('p').sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).text().length - $(b).text().length;
}).last();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/UM953/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have them all in the body and they are all enclosed in `<p>` tags you could do:

```
var longestLength=0, longestElement;
$("body p").each(function(){

    if($(this).html().length > longestLength)
    {
        lonestLength = $(this).html().length;
        longestElement = this;
    }

});

   $(longestElement).addClass('myClass');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var $most = $("p").first();

$("p").each(function(){
    if($most != null && $(this).text().length > $most.text().length){
        $most = $(this);
    }
});

$most.addClass("longest");
```

With this; you can count just characters, not html elements. And add class to the longest.

Test here: http://jsfiddle.net/s9N5g/